How to run pom.xml inside eclipse on jdk 17 and can I change jdk 17 to jdk 11 inside eclipse
I am using maven 3.9.3 and jdk 17 in eclipse (see 3 imgsenter image description hereenter image description here)enter image description hereenter image description here
But now I am changed from jdk 17 to  jdk 11 then I am able to run pom.xml inside eclipse
I want to run pom.xml on jdk 17 how can we do that
I saw copatible version jdk for maven.i can run only on jdk 11 but i want to run on jdk 17 or latest version.
do i need to change maven version (compiler and surefire plugin also).how can i change it.

https://www.phind.com/search?q=How+to+set+the+java+version+17+in+Maven+POM and make sure that in the preferences Java > Installed JREs a Java 17 JDK is configured.

I tried same,but its not working for me ,getting mojo exception

So it is working, but your Mojo is not ready for Java 17 (maybe because your Mojo uses reflection, which became more restrictive in Java 16 and 17).
